# Making group optional at end of regex causes it to be never matched

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex in PHP to match some text like this:

> 24th Meeting - The quick brown fox [10 January 2012 to 26 September
>   2012]

The pattern I've come up with looks like this:

```
$pattern = "/(([0-9]{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)\sMeeting\s-\s)?(.*)(\[([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\sto\s([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\])$/"
```

This seems to work fine.

However, I would like the date portion at the end to be optional. BUT, when I add a ? after the dates grouping, preg_match no longer pulls out the dates if they are in the string. I suspect that the .* is taking over, but I can't seem to get it

Comment: does changing the .* to [^[]* solve your problem?
it will not work if you can have square brackets in the medium part of the text

Comment: Make your regex more readable with the `/x` flag first.

Comment: @rbernabe this didn't work - I tried a couple of variations, but no joy

Comment: I'm typing up an elaborate answer for you, give me a few rodders. @mario: Use http://regex101.com/ -- makes stuff a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*) --> (.*?)
```

Read more about lazy quantifiers here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: This worked! Excellent, thank you! (This was one of the first things I tried before I posted, but it didn't work for me - I must have had other issues when I tried it earlier)

Answer (score 0):

Just as you presumed, the `.*` (greedy quantifier) eats up too much information. This can be solved either by making it *lazy* or replacing it with something else such as `[^[]*`. However, replacing it with the latter suggestion will disallow any use of the literal `[` in the string.

What you should also do, besides fixing this issue, is learn to use non-capturing groups for the parts you don't need saved. This will speed up your regexes and save some memory.

Here's my solution to your problem. Not much changed, but I'm sure you can spot the differences.

```
/(([0-9]{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)\sMeeting\s-\s)?(.*)(\[([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\sto\s([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\])?$/
```

You can view a demo and an explanation to the regular expression here: http://regex101.com/r/vZ1nH6

The website uses PHP so it's accurate to your problem. If you are interested in learning more I suggest you read up on regular expressions over at www.regular-expressions.info and have a look at the quiz over at http://www.regex101.com/quiz/

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried this: [^[]* but I got a compilation error. I tried escaping the [] chars but still didn't work. Using (.*?) works for me now - not sure why it didn't the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

This little changes will do it (bold)

`/(([0-9]{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)\sMeeting\s-\s)?` **`(.*?)`** `(\[([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\sto\s([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\]`**`|$`**`)$/`

first the freetext expression is extended by a `?` to make it ungreedy (see the other posts)

than `|$` is appended to the date part to tell it to be exactly the date or the end of the string.

Here's your total regex

`/(([0-9]{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)\sMeeting\s-\s)?(.*?)(\[([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\sto\s([0-9]{1,2}\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|November|December)\s[0-9]{4})\]|$)$/`